# How make $.ajaxSetup rely on a backbone.js model initialized later

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, initialization, jquery-deferred

I have the following backbone.js application initialization process :

```
var app = {
  init: function(arg) {
    $.when(app.loadStaticFiles('any_file_to_load_before'))
    .done(function(args) {
       app.models.current_user = app.Models.User();
     });
    // ... 
    // initializing the backbone app and models
    // ...
    $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {Authorization: 'Token token=' + app.models.current_user.get('token')}
    })
  }    
}
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    app.init(args);
  };
);
```

Then when the application initialize the $.ajaxSetup evaluates the `app.models.current_user.get('token')` which sadly is not defined.

I guess there are some missconceptions in my design, how should I rewrite my code in order to make it work ?

I think the main problem is the evaluation of `$.ajaxSetup()` before the `$.deferred` resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deferreds are meant to control the order of your application's processes.  From reading your question, it seems that your application's order needs to be:

1. `app.loadStaticFiles('any_file_to_load_before')`
2. `app.models.current_user = app.Models.User();`
3. `$.ajaxSetup(...)`
4. initializing the backbone app and models?

You would write this using deferreds as:

```
var app = {
  init: function(arg) {
    $.when(app.loadStaticFiles('any_file_to_load_before'))
      .done(function(args) {
        app.models.current_user = app.Models.User();
      })
      .done(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {Authorization: 'Token token=' + app.models.current_user.get('token')}
        })
      })
      .done(function() {
        // ... 
        // initializing the backbone app and models
        // ...
      });
   }
};
```

A tiny detail to note has to do with jQuery's implied ordering of `done()` callbacks.  In this code, you are only doing 4 static steps.  If you needed a specific ordering and were adding `.done()` callbacks dynamically, you might not be sure which one was added before the others.  This above example works because jQuery runs the `.done()` callbacks in the order they are added.  If you didn't have this assumption, you would have to proxy/filter the deferred at each done step through jQuery's `.then()` function instead.  This way each intermediate step would only have 1 and only 1 done callback that returned another deferred for the next one to attach 1 and only 1 callback ... and so on.